# MFMailComposeViewController in iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, email, sendmail

hii every one

can we use  " MFMailComposeViewController "  with out using " presentModalViewController" , i mean i need to send email with out navigating to that mail composer page

i did a test project with following code

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed {
    arrRecipients = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [arrRecipients addObject:@"xxxxxxx@gmail.com"];


    MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mailController setSubject:@"Ravikiran test mail"];
    [mailController setToRecipients:arrRecipients];

    [mailController setMessageBody:@"this is my test app" isHTML:YES];
    [self presentModalViewController:mailController animated:YES];
    [mailController release];
}
```

it is sending mail but it is navigating to mail composer page  & then its sending but i need to send mail just on click of the button

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use `MFMailComposeViewController` to send an email without user interaction.  There are probably 3rd parties libraries that let you do this, but the iOS SDK does not allow you to.

Also, you're leaking the `arrRecipients` array.

Comment: oh i see,is there any other way to meet my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Best way for your needs is to have a web service  which sends the data to an email id.
its always to good to inform the user in some way before sending the mail.

Thanks!